# "Call to a possibly undefined method" - big project

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

im working on a side scrolling game project but ive been struggling with AS files. 1st of all i did not code on the main time line frame one, i use external as files for the entire project.

So far i have 2 separate as files, main one named Tuan.as and the other one Enemy.as

i have no problem running with Tuan.as file alone however when i decided to add more features to the game like adding enemy by using another as file called Enemy.as and i couldnt import them properly. i got the error **"Call to a possibly undefined method addEnemytoLevel1"**

Here is the code of my entire game, the first file Tuan.as:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Tuan extends MovieClip {


    public var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    public var mySound:Sound = new general();



    public var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var downPressed:Boolean = false;

    public var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
    public var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
    public var upBumping:Boolean = false;
    public var downBumping:Boolean = false;

    public var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -55);
    public var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -55);
    public var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, -120);
    public var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);

    public var scrollX:Number = 0;
    public var scrollY:Number = 500;

    public var xSpeed:Number = 0;
    public var ySpeed:Number = 0;

    public var speedConstant:Number = 4;
    public var frictionConstant:Number = 0.9;
    public var gravityConstant:Number = 1.8;
    public var jumpConstant:Number = -35;
    public var maxSpeedConstant:Number = 18;

    public var doubleJumpReady:Boolean = false;
    public var upReleasedInAir:Boolean = false;

    private var keyCollected:Boolean = false;
    private var keyCollected2:Boolean = false;
    private var keyCollected3:Boolean = false;
    private var keyCollected4:Boolean = false;
    private var keyCollected5:Boolean = false;
    private var keyCollected6:Boolean = false;
    private var keyCollected7:Boolean = false;
    private var keyCollected8:Boolean = false;

    var enemyList:Array = new Array();      
    public var doorOpen:Boolean = false;

     public var nakedboard:Boolean = false;
     public var currentLevel:int = 1;

    addEnemiesToLevel1();

    public function addEnemiesToLevel1():void{
    addEnemy(620, -115);
    addEnemy(900, -490);
    addEnemy(2005, -115);
    addEnemy(1225, -875);
    }

    public function Tuan() {


        myChannel = mySound.play(0, 9999);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

    }


    public function loop(e:Event):void{
        if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x, player.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)){
            //trace("leftBumping");
            leftBumping = true;
        } else {
            leftBumping = false;
        }

        if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x, player.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)){
            //trace("rightBumping");
            rightBumping = true;
        } else {
            rightBumping = false;
        }

        if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x, player.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)){
            //trace("upBumping");
            upBumping = true;
        } else {
            upBumping = false;
        }

        if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)){
            //trace("downBumping");
            downBumping = true;
        } else {
            downBumping = false;
        }   


        if(leftPressed){
            xSpeed -= speedConstant;
            player.scaleX = -1;

        } else if(rightPressed){
            xSpeed += speedConstant;
            player.scaleX = 1;
        }


        if(leftBumping){
            if(xSpeed < 0){
                xSpeed *= -0.5;
            }
        }

        if(rightBumping){
            if(xSpeed > 0){
                xSpeed *= -0.5;
            }
        }

        if(upBumping){
            if(ySpeed < 0){
                ySpeed *= -0.5;
            }
        }

        if(downBumping){ //if the character touches the floor
            if(ySpeed > 0){ 
                ySpeed = 0; //set the y speed to zero
            }
            if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
                ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
            }

            //DOUBLE JUMP
            if(upReleasedInAir == true){
                upReleasedInAir = false;
            }
            if(doubleJumpReady == false){
                doubleJumpReady = true;
            }
        } else { //if we are not touching the floor

            ySpeed += gravityConstant; //accelerate downwards

            if(upPressed == false && upReleasedInAir == false){
                upReleasedInAir = true;
                //trace("upReleasedInAir");
            }
            if(doubleJumpReady && upReleasedInAir){
                if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
                    //trace("doubleJump!");
                    doubleJumpReady = false;
                    ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
                }
            }

        }

        if(xSpeed > maxSpeedConstant){ //moving right
            xSpeed = maxSpeedConstant;
        } else if(xSpeed < (maxSpeedConstant * -1)){ //moving left
            xSpeed = (maxSpeedConstant * -1);
        }

        xSpeed *= frictionConstant;
        ySpeed *= frictionConstant;

        if(Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.5){
            xSpeed = 0;
        }

        scrollX -= xSpeed;
        scrollY -= ySpeed;

        back.x = scrollX;
        back.y = scrollY;

        cave.x = scrollX * 0.2;
        cave.y = scrollY * 0.2;


if (nakedboard == false){
            if(player.hitTestObject(back.nakedboard)){
                back.nakedboard.gotoAndPlay(2);

            }
        }
        if(keyCollected == false ){
            if(player.hitTestObject(back.puzzle.redKey)){
                back.puzzle.redKey.visible = false;
                keyCollected2 = true;

                trace("need next key")

                }
            }
        if (keyCollected2 == true ){
            if(player.hitTestObject(back.puzzle.orangeKey)){
                back.puzzle.orangeKey.visible = false;
                keyCollected3 = true;

            } 
        }

        if(doorOpen == false){
            if(keyCollected3 == true){
                if(player.hitTestObject(back.puzzle.lockedDoor)){
                    back.puzzle.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(2);
                    doorOpen = true;

                    trace("door open");
                }
            }
        }       


    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    public function gotoLevel2():void{
        back.nakedboard.gotoAndStop(1);
        back.puzzle.gotoAndStop(2);
        back.visuals.gotoAndStop(2);
        back.collisions.gotoAndStop(2);
        scrollX = 0;
        scrollY = 500;
        back.puzzle.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(1);
        /*back.other.doorKey1.visible = true;*/


    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function gotoLevel3():void{

        back.puzzle.gotoAndStop(3);
        back.visuals.gotoAndStop(3);
        back.collisions.gotoAndStop(3);
        scrollX = 0;
        scrollY = 500;

    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function nextLevel():void{
        currentLevel++;
        trace("Next Level: " + currentLevel);
        if(currentLevel == 2){
           gotoLevel2();
        }
        // can be extended...
         else if(currentLevel == 3) { 
             gotoLevel3(); 
             }  
    }

    public function addEnemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int):void
{
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(xLocation, yLocation);
    back.addChild(enemy);

    enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
    enemyList.push(enemy);
}
    public function enemyRemoved(e:Event):void
{
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
}

    public function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftPressed = true;

        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightPressed = true;

        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            upPressed = true;

        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            downPressed = true;
            if(doorOpen && player.hitTestObject(back.puzzle.lockedDoor)){
                nextLevel();
                myChannel.stop();

            }
        }   
    }

    public function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftPressed = false;

        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightPressed = false;

        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            upPressed = false;

        } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            downPressed = false;
        }   
    }
}
```

}

and this is the Enemy.as file:

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Enemy extends MovieClip{

    public function Enemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int)
    {
        // constructor code
        x = xLocation;
        y = yLocation;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }

    public function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        //the looping code goes here
    }

    public function removeSelf():void
    {
        trace("remove self");
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop); //stop the loop
        this.parent.removeChild(this); //tell this object's "parent object" to remove this object
    }
}
```

}

im not really good at AS if dont wanna say very bad, i cant figure out how to get it work, so much appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean `addEnemiesToLevel1()` ( add enemies to level 1 ) and not `addEnemytoLevel1()`, which you can not call like that, it should be called inside another function of your class if used inside it, and in your case, you can call it inside the constructor :

```
public function Tuan()
{
    // ...

    addEnemiesToLevel1();
}
```

Hope that can help.